# Spring boot actuator health endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have create a PostgreSQL health indicator like this:

```
@Component
public class PostgresHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    @Autowired
    DataSource postgresDataSource;

    public DataSourceHealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator() {
        DataSourceHealthIndicator indicator = new DataSourceHealthIndicator(postgresDataSource);
        return indicator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
        Health h = dbHealthIndicator().health();
        Status status = h.getStatus();
        if (status != null && "DOWN".equals(status.getCode())) {
            builder.down();
        } else {
            builder.up();
        }
    }
}
```

In my Application.java I am scanning this package for this component:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.bp.health"})
```

In my application.properties I have the following set:

```
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
endpoints.health.id=health
endpoints.health.enabled=true
```

when I hit {url}/health I see:

> {"status":"DOWN"}

what do I need to do to get the custom health indicator to show?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to be authenticated to see all the details.
Alternatively you could set

```
management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
```

to see full content unauthenticated

More information about that can be found here:
[Production ready monitoring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do all that? That code doesn't even compile and Spring Boot does check your data sources by default already. If you only see the status, that's because you're not authenticated, check this table [in the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health-access-restrictions) for more details.